# How to query on DATE on DATETIME Column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select

Here is my table having column(**completed_on**) with `datetime` field.
However I need to filter results based on `date` only.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE completed_on 
-- Pass Date Range in condition
```

[image]

Comment: What is your issue? This is trivially easy to search for. You have 2k plus rep, come on....

Comment: Haha... That doesn't mean I am expert in SQL ;-). Never mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tyr this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE completed_on BETWEEN 'date1' and 'Date2'
-- Pass Date Range in condition
```

Another option is-

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE completed_on >= '20190701' --Sample start Date 
and completed_on < '20190722' 
-- This will make sure dates will be inclued less then 
-- the given date. You have to pass this with 
-- understanding what you want. If you want 
-- date 7 to be included, please set the end date to 8
```

Comment: Yeah, That's correct but **date2** is not included in result. Is there any way to include it as well in result?

Comment: Don't use BETWEEN for dates.

Comment: @dfundako What's your suggestion?

Comment: Yeshhh.. That's correct now. Thanks mkRabbani and dfundako.

Comment: When the column is `datetime`, [`BETWEEN` just doesn't make sense here at all](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).